# How to loop through all lines in a file except last in python?

Tags: python

I want to loop through all lines except last and print them.
I was able to find some shell commands that print all lines except last, but i would like to use python to go over all lines except last. Pleas help.

Comment: last lines of what may i ask?

Comment: Why not loop through all lines but just treat the last line differently? Is *reading* the last line going to do any harm?

Comment: yes, i am parsing the lines based on delimiters and storing them elsewhere, the alst line isn't what i want to store.

Comment: Read the file into a single string, split on `\n` -- then `pop` off the last one.

Comment: If the next line is null do something differently

Comment: Does not show any effort.. searching google for the first exact sentence would give the exact answer at 1st place.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to read each line, save it, then work with them on the *next* iteration. That way, you never process the last line.

```
prev_line = None
for line in filehandler:
    if prev_line is not None:
        print prev_line
    prev_line = line
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, could you explain a bit more

Comment: When you read the first line, `prev_line` is `None` so  you don't do anything with it. When you read the `n`th line, `prev_line` is the (n-1)th line. When you read the last line, `prev_line` is the next-to-last line. After you set it to the last line, you exit the loop so that it never gets used.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do this is to use a list slice that excludes the very last element of the list.

```
def print_lines(lst):
   for line in lst[0:len(lst)-1]:
      print(line)
```

This approach doesn't depend on whether or not a newline character is present at the end of the last line or not.

Comment: Thanks. But im looping through the file like "for line in filehandler:". I am not passing a list

Comment: Good for the slicing approach, but can be as simple as `lst[:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code:

```
In [1]: with open(filename) as f:
   ...:     data = f.read().split('\n')
   ...:     

In [2]: for id in range(len(data) -1):
   ...:     print data[id]
   ...:
```